# Indentation script does not work for all occurrence

Tags: command-line, indentation

I have following `c.vim` file:

```
imap {<CR> {<CR>}<Esc>O
imap [ []<Left>
imap # #include<><Left>

command F %s/\v(\w) ?(\+|-|\*|\/|\>\=|\<\=|!\=|\=|\=\=) ?(\w|-)/\1 \2 \3/g | %s/\v([;,])([^ ])/\1 \2/g
```

And my sample file is `test.c` containing

```c
if(a==3)
if(array[4]==3)
```

Then if I execute command `F` then the above file is changed into

```c
if(a == 3)
if(array[4]==3)
```

First `==` sign is indented but not in second. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only relevant part is the first substitution in the `F` command:

```
%s/\v(\w) ?(\+|-|\*|\/|\>\=|\<\=|!\=|\=|\=\=) ?(\w|-)/\1 \2 \3/g
```

Breaking down the pattern:

- `\v` - set 'very magic' option, many characters have special meaning without having to be escaped
- `(\w)` - match one `word` character which is same as `[0-9A-Za-z_]`, the parens allow this match to be inserted into the substitution via back-reference (e.g. `\1`)
- `<space>?` - match 0 or 1 space
- `(\+|-|\*|\/|\>\=|\<\=|!\=|\=|\=\=)` - match an arithmetic operator, surrounding with parens for back-ref use
- `<space>?` - match 0 or 1 space
- `(\w|-)` - same as `(\w)` above except also allow dash to match

(The substitution `\1 \2 \3`, with back-reference to each of the paren surrounded pattern parts, adds an extra space before and after the arithmetic operator.)

It should be pretty clear now from the breakdown of the pattern that `a==3` matches and `array[4]==3` does not as the character preceding the operator, i.e. `]`, is not a `word` character. One option to allow `]` as well is to replace `(\w)` with `([]0-9A-Za-z_])` or `(]|\w)`. Choosing the latter we end up with this for `F`:

```
command F %s/\v(]|\w) ?(\+|-|\*|\/|\>\=|\<\=|!\=|\=|\=\=) ?(\w|-)/\1 \2 \3/g | %s/\v([;,])([^ ])/\1 \2/g
```